# How to force HTML mode in emails from Nodemailer

Tags: nodemailer

I was sending emails from my Node app when it was running on my localhost and they came into my Outlook beautifully as HTML emails with correct formatting.  I published the app to our web server and tested it and now the emails are coming in as plaintext and I can see all the `br` tags and `span` tags, etc.  I'm wondering what could be triggering this change between the environments?  Is there a way to force HTML emails?

I set up the mailOptions object exactly the same and I have verified the NodeMailer versions are the same.

```js
const mailOptions = {
            from, // sender address
            to, // list of receivers
            subject, // Subject line
            //text: body, // plain text body
            html: body
            //html: // html body
        };
        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error) => {
            if (error) {
                reject('Email not sent!');
            } else {
                resolve('Email sent!');
            }
        });
```

Email sent from web server:
[image]

Email sent from my local machine:

[image]

Comment: Forgive my "get off my lawn" rant: mail *should* be sent in both formats. 

As for what to do, I'd first look at a couple of things: whether the webserver has all the same packages installed as localhost does, and whether a raw mail contains a header with a multipart/MIME Content entity so your MUA can interpret it properly.

Comment: I appreciate the comment.  It didn't occur to me to always include both types, but it makes sense.  I added code in for both types and now for whatever reason, I am receiving HTML emails!  :)  I'll call that a win!  Thank you so much!